# GCP PubSub and Cloud Run unacked message more than 5 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

We are working with **GCP Cloud Run** and **PubSub** subscription in that, the Cloud Run instance is the subscriber for the messages coming into the PubSub.
Currently, there is an alert set up for `oldest_unacked_message_age` in the queue and it is raised if it is over 5 seconds.

Most of the time, the message flow is fine but sometimes we get the alert gets raised for `oldest_unacked_message_age` which varies between **6.5 - 61.5** seconds and eventually the message gets delivered. The logs show nothing out of the ordinary.

Can these be treated as false positives? Or is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Is it a push or a pull subscription?

Comment: It is a pull subscription.

Comment: How do you trigger the pulling mechanism with Cloud Run? Do you perform a HTTP request? If so, how do you handle it? Do you have piece of code to share?